# How to create a Treeview with Glade and Gtk?

Tags: python, treeview, gtk, glade

I am trying to build an interface with Glade and Gtk.

In Glade : I created a liststore labeled liststore. I added no column to that liststore.
I then created a treeview labeled treeview and I chose liststore as a model for that treeview.

This is my code :

```
class CellRenderePartitions(Gtk.Box):
    self.liststore = builder.get_object('liststore')
    self.treeview = builder.get_object('treeview')
    self.treeview.model = self.liststore

    media = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    col = Gtk.treeViewColumn("Media",media,text=1)
    col.set_sizing(Gtk.TreeViewColumnSizing.AUTOSIZE)
    col.set_expand(True)

    self.liststore.append(None)
```

I get this error :

Gtk_CRITICAL **: gtk_list_store_get_vlue: assertion column < priv->n_columns' failed

I know that the last line of my code is causing this trouble but I do not understand why, can anyone help ?

Comment: As an aside, did you know that you can setup your renderers in Glade by right clicking the treeview?

Comment: Thank you I added columns and text renderers to the column and now I can see 3 columns and an empty row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in your own question. You don't have a column in your liststore, but you append some data to it. And yes, appending a `None` will be considered as a value, so you need a column to store that in.

Comment: Thank you for your help I fixed the problem. I know have 3 columns and one empty row. Howerver if I try to add another row with the command self.liststore.append(["value1","value2","value3"]) it just adds another empty row and I can not explain why..

Comment: Finally found out my mistake.. to be able to see the text, I had to edit the treeview, to edit the CellRendererText properties and attributs by setting "Text" to the appropriate column.